# How to load google map geo-location not using kml

Tags: javascript, python, django, google-maps, kml

How to load google map geo-location not using kml. Like this site: http://www.housingmaps.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This example](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/examples/marker-simple.html) from Google is what you're looking for.